# Slow processing of all images by google face API?

Tags: java, android, performance, face-api

I am making an android app which is using the Google face API to detect faces of all the images in the gallery. It is taking a long time to process all the images and hence the apps get stuck for a long time. Any workaround?
I tried reducing the size of the image and then process, but it gives a faulty answer on it.

Comment: Have you tried running this code asynchronous? It's normal this takes a while, so you should make sure it doesn't block you UI.

Comment: It takes around 25 seconds to process 50 images, so even if I make it async then also the time taken is really long to process a large number of pictures.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

2 minutes for 715 images is a really good time.
Steps that can be taken:

1. enable fast mode in FaceDetector
2. set setTrackingEnabled to false if you don't want to track
3. set minimum face size to an appropriate size according to your dataset
4. Load the bitmaps using Universal Image Loader or glide library of Android. I used the UIL library.
5. 640x480 is an optimum size for face detection and classification for scale down the size for less time and almost the same result.
6. Set setLandmarkType and setClassificationType according to your needs and disable if not required.

Answer (score 0):

Disable the **image tracking** :

```
    FaceDetector detector = new FaceDetector.Builder(context)
            .setTrackingEnabled(false)
            .build();
```

It's `true` by default, and may slow the detection if you don't need this feature.

Comment: It is false by default in my case.

Answer (score 0):

If you look in the documentation of the [`FaceDetector.Builder`](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/vision/face/FaceDetector.Builder) you will see that you can set some properties that will increase the speed.

E.g.:

```
public FaceDetector.Builder setProminentFaceOnly (boolean prominentFaceOnly)
```

Comment: I tried using universal image loader library to create the bitmaps and then use those bitmaps for creating frames for face detection.

Comment: Most of my images dont really have multiple faces so it does not create a significant difference.
I am unsure if it possible to reduce the time more than what I have done till now.

Comment: It takes around 2 minutes and 15 seconds to detect faces in 715 images.

Comment: 'setProminentFaceOnly' will actually increase speed because the Face API will search the rest of the photo for other faces. Even if you know there is only one face, the API doesn't.

Comment: Another function 'setMinFaceSize' should also help. If you know the photos have only one face in close-up then you can specify a higher value (e.g.: 0.5), which will then decrease the time again.

Comment: I tried that but it is of no use as it decreased the accuracy by quite a lot.